# Adding a unique class to wp_nav_menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

How would I go about adding a unique class to the direct child li elements of the main parent ul element generated with wp_nav_menu?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu_element"></div>
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
  <div class="menu-main-container">
    <ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://www.site/page1-2/">Page1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="http://www.site/sub-page1-1/">Sub-Page1-1</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49"><a href="http://www.site/sub-page1-2/">Sub-Page1-2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#menu-main > .menu-item').mouseenter(function (){
    $('.menu_element').appendTo(this);
    hoverOn();
});
$('#menu-main > .menu-item').mouseleave(function (){
    hoverOff(); 
    $(this).remove($('.menu_element'));
});
```

I'd like to add the class `menu_element` to `li id="menu-item-30"` and every child li of the parent ul after. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the reasoning behind this so you can target the root `li`s in your css?

Comment: I actually want to manipulate the root li s with jQuery, but there are multiple classes for each li element, so I need to find a way to add a unique class.

Comment: I've been attempting to implement http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Adding_Conditional_Classes_to_Menu_Items with no luck.

Comment: With jquery you can target only the root list items using `.menu > .menu-item` as your selector

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that but it doesn't seem to be working with wp_nav_menu.  Not sure if it has something to do with the fact that I'm using a menu plugin which is why i'd like to assign a class with PHP and see what happens.

Comment: @ddc018 Care to share the jquery code as well?

Comment: jQuery posted, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I just added an answer to [the same question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53110/adding-a-unique-class-to-wp-nav-menu) on WordPress Answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is for `.menu-main` (a `class`) when you have it as an `id`. You need:

```
$('#menu-main > .menu-item').mouseenter(function (){
    $('.menu_element').appendTo(this);
    hoverOn();
});
$('#menu-main > .menu-item').mouseleave(function (){
    hoverOff(); 
    $(this).remove($('.menu_element'));
});
```

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I have the correct markup in my document.

Comment: @ScottS-it doesnt work because of the menu plugin I'm using, it's overriding any script I try to add for some reason.  clioweb's answer seems to work for what I need.  Thanks!